# Heroku Cedar-14 heroku-geo-buildpack GEOSException

Tags: heroku, geodjango, cedar

I recently updated my heroku cedar from Bamboo to Cedar-14. 
I had a geodjango buildpack installed which is now failing with this error: 
    OGRException: OGR failure.

This is my buildpacks:

```
cat .buildpacks

https://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
https://github.com/gregburek/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer.git#v0.3.2
```

This is my runtime:

```
cat runtime.txt

python-2.7.8
```

Is there a buildpack for geodjango that workis good on Cedar-14?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this issue by doing this:

- Changed my .buildpack file to look like this:

  https://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango.git#1.1
  https://github.com/gregburek/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer.git#v0.3.2

I used here the latest release of the heroku-buildpack-geodjango by checking their release tags and specifying the latest one.

- I ended up using this runtime.txt:

  python-2.7.9
- I made sure I had the following enviroment varialbles pointing to the correct location which is:

  heroku config:set GDAL_DATA=.geodjango/gdal/share/gdal

  heroku config:set GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH=.geodjango/gdal/lib/libgdal.so

  heroku config:set GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=.geodjango/geos/lib/libgeos_c.so

There is also an issue opened recently which explains more in this link:
https://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango/issues/8